# What happens if there's a veto on the European Union budget?

Tags: european-union, budget, veto

Recently Hungary and Poland vetoed (or formally just threaten to use a veto) on the EU budget (see for example [here](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/nov/16/eu-hungary-veto-budget-viktor-orban)). What happens in 2021 if there's no accepted budget? The referred article mentions that "projects financed by the bloc’s seven-year budget will go without funds", but elsewhere (Facebook comments, sorry) I read that the budget from previous years will stay in power. Also the EU budget contains more than "projects", for example income from the member states, salaries of the employees at the EU headquarters, etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 2014, the rule was that the previous annual budget would be carried over.  It's unlikely that this rule will have changed in the intervening period.

[Source: BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-21377378)